ec2 instance ssh and instance connect is not working
I launched an ec2 instance in eu-north-1 Stockholm and try to connect to instance using ssh and instance connect but both of this is not working.
EC2 Instance Details
EC2 Instance Connect
EC2 Instance Security Group
SSH Connection Timed Out
And, this problem is coming in this specific region only. I tried to create instance in
ap-south-1 Mumbai region and there it is working fine.
Is there any region specific configuration in eu-north-1?

Did you install EC2 Instance Connect on your instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html

No, I didn't install EC2 instance connect on instance, and also for that I need to connect to instance but ssh is also not working.

Was the instance launched in a public subnet (defined as having a Route Table pointing to an Internet Gateway)?

yes, It is launched in public subnet.
